# Printf solo se ejecuta la primera vez

Tags: c, windows, printf, mingw

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    }
    
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        }else if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
            ++nwhite;
        }else{
            ++nother;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Digitos =");
    
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        printf(" %d,", ndigit[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\nEspacios blancos = %d\nOtros = %d", nwhite, nother);
    
}
```

Compila sin problemas, pero al ejecutarlo e introducir números al azar obtengo lo siguiente:

```
1234556677

Digitos =
```

Solo se ejecuta el primer printf y no me muestra lo demás. Probé comentando todo el bucle while y ahí si se muestran todos los printf's por lo que creo debe ser algún problema el getchar() pero no logro solucionarlo.

Estoy usando el compilador Mingw directamente desde la consola de windows sin IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos problemas:

- En un programa interactivo, `getchar` va a detener la ejecución del programa esperando nueva información.
- `EOF` significa *final del archivo* (**E**nd **O**f **F**ile). Como una consola interactiva no es precisamente un archivo, la única forma de enviar `EOF` al programa es mediante [una combinación de teclas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16136924/13419694).

Lo que puedes hacer es:

- Dejar el código así y enviar la combinación de teclas o redirigir un archivo a la entrada del programa.

  Puedes hacerlo con `<`:

  ```
  programa < archivo.txt
  ```
- Modificarlo para que pare cuando se encuentre otro carácter o secuencia de caracteres. Por ejemplo, un salto de línea `'\n'`:

  ```
  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF && c != '\n'){
      if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
          int digit = c - '0';
          ++ndigit[digit];
      }else if(c == ' ' || c == '\t'){
          ++nwhite;
      }else{
          ++nother;
      }
      c = getchar();
  }
  ```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, aunque solo lee una linea de texto. Y eso de "<" es un comando de la consola?

Comment: @ClynnJDev así es. Y sirve para Windows y *nix.

Comment: Tambien donde estaba fallando es que intentaba introducir EOF con Ctrl+C, ahora me entero que es Ctrl+Z.